# Why is image broken in the template by using flask upload?

Tags: image, flask, upload, flask-uploads

Everytime I upload photos into the `files` folder, the page does not displaying it into the   `post.html` template. The only thing I see is the `broken image icon` . Here is the code.

**Config**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, '.env'))


class Config(object):

UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS = '.jpg', '.png', '.gif'
    UPLOAD_PATH = 'app/static/files'
```

**Route**

```
def validate_image(stream):
    header = stream.read(512)  # 512 bytes should be enough for a header check
    stream.seek(0)  # reset stream pointer
    format = imghdr.what(None, header)
    if not format:
        return None
    return '.' + (format if format != 'jpeg' else 'jpg')

@bp.route('/photos')
def photos():
    files = os.listdir(current_app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])
    return render_template('photos.html', files=files)


@bp.route('/photos', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
    if filename != '':
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if file_ext not in current_app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] or \
                file_ext != validate_image(uploaded_file.stream):
            abort(400)
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('main.photos'))

@bp.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def upload(filename):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block app_content %}

<h1>File Upload</h1>
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/photos" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<hr>
{% for file in files %}
  <img src="{{ url_for('main.upload', filename=files) }}" style="width: 125px">

{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Was it successfully uploaded and stored? What's the output URL and response header?

Comment: Also: Change `url_for('main.upload', filename=files)` to `url_for('bp.uploads', filename=file)`

Comment: No I think it is right, because I get an error in the front line.

Comment: The route might be correct, but you are passing `files` instead of `file`.

Comment: It does not change anything, either if I pass file or files. It gives me the same results.

Comment: You can expand your question with more code in order to be able to run it. You can also check and share the final URL the browser receives and is unable to load.

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` tag in the template is incorrect. You have `filename=files`, but it should be `filename=file`.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('main.upload', filename=file) }}" style="width: 125px">
```

Comment: I am wondering how to approach this if I want to post the same file name or the picture. ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Maybe you need to write a separate question?

Comment: I meant how to upload the same filename to be duplicate on the page? Like you have two same pictures on the same page.  Every time I do that it does add to the page.

Comment: Sorry, this is still confusing. You wrote your application to override filenames. If you want to keep duplicates, don't overwrite existing filenames when a duplicate is uploaded.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Could you please take a look at my question here. It is from your project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292598/how-to-sort-multiple-elements-by-date-in-flask?noredirect=1#comment115430928_65292598